# User Input of Integers Infinite Loop Until User Inputs a Character (C)

Tags: c, loops, integer, character, user-input

i'm new to C - I have intended to make a program that shows whether the user input `int` is `odd` or `even`, until the user decides to quit by inputing a `char` '`x`'. The loop kind of works by detecting odd numbers and terminating the program with 'x', however glitches with even numbers - why is that so? Would appreciate it if you could point out the flaws in the code. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
int i=0;
char x = "x";

printf("Enter an integer to check whether your number is odd or even\n");
printf("Enter an ´x´ at any time to quit the program\n");

do
{ 
    scanf("%d", &i);
    
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
        {
            printf("The number is even\n");
        }
        else if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            printf("The number is odd\n");
        }   
        else("%c ", &x);
        {
            scanf(" %c", &x);
            getchar();
            printf("The program will now terminate\n");
            return 0;
        }
}
    while (i > 0);
        i++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `else("%c ", &x);` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close but I've marked a couple of changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
int i=0;
char x = 'x';  // Note: single quotes for char, double for string

printf("Enter an integer to check whether your number is odd or even\n");
printf("Enter an ´x´ at any time to quit the program\n");

do
{ 
    int n = scanf("%d", &i);  // Check if number was read
    if (n == 1) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
        {
            printf("The number is even\n");
        }
        else  // Only other possibility
        {
            printf("The number is odd\n");
        }

    } else   // No number, see if there's an 'x'
    {
            scanf(" %c", &x);
            if (x == 'x') 
            {
                 printf("The program will now terminate\n");
                 return 0;
            } else
            {
                 printf("Unknown input %c\n", x);
            }
    }
}
    while (i > 0);  // Will also end if user enters <= 0

    return 0;
}
```