# User Input of Integers Infinite Loop Until User Inputs a Character (C language)

Tags: c, infinite

[User Input of Integers Infinite Loop Until User Inputs a Character (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887232/user-input-of-integers-infinite-loop-until-user-inputs-a-character-c)

```
int n = scanf("%d", &i);  
if (n == 1) {
```

can somebody explain me this part I am unable to understand why equality operator does not give false as output and jumps to else statement??

i am a beginner and don't much about these complicated syntax.
Pls help me

```
   int n = scanf("%d", &i);  
    if (n == 1) {
```

if i give 5 as input then value of n will be 5 and when it goes to if statement then (5==1) will execute which will results as false but in this answer it not that case ?

Comment: Read (again) what [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) actually returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that certainly is not the case.
As per the man page:

**RETURN VALUE**

> On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

So in the case of a single integer, if `scanf` was successful in reading and assigning it to a memory address as specified in the second argument, it will returns the number of elements successfully processed.

**Aside:**

You do not need to declare another variable and assign the return value of scanf to it, you could test for it directly:

```
if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) { 
    ..deal with invalid input..
}
```